# Remote connection between a website and local computer

Tags: web-services, http, localhost, remote-access

Is there any way I can connect to a local computer from internet website..

My requirement is to develop an Asp.Net web application which need to communicate with a local database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem you have to solve is to get a static IP. You can do this by setting up an account on http://www.dyndns.com. Second thing you need is to configure your router at home to update dyndns.com automatically and open and redirect the needed port to your local PC.

That's all you have to do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. In other words I have to turn my local PC to behave like a web server, right? Let me see if the client can do this ;)